# Explicit polynomial for quadratic elements? (FEM)

Tags: finite-element, differential-equations, polynomials, partitioning

In [this resource](http://hplgit.github.io/INF5620/doc/pub/sphinx-fem/._main_fem009.html) the linear (barycentric) elements are explicitly given:

[image]

The geometry placement of higher order elements is also given but not expression for the polynomial of $P_2$ is given. I am hoping someone can tell me what the 6 polynomials look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be an interpolation basis, for each node $i$ there must be a polynomial $\phi_i(\vec{r})$ such that
$$
\phi_i(\vec{r}_j) = \delta_{ij}
$$
where $\vec{r}_j$ is the coordinate location of node $j$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Kronecker%20delta,of%20variables%20i%20and%20j.).

The easiest way to derive a set of polynomials which satisfies these requirements is to draw "lines" which pass through every single node except for 1, and then require a polynomial to be zero on those lines, and then scale it appropriately to be 1 at the remaining node. The number of lines you are allowed to use is equal to the polynomial degree of your basis.

For example, take the 2nd order parabolic element:

[image]

To be zero on the red lines for node 0, we need
$$
P_0(x, y) = (1 - x - y) \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}\right)
$$
Then to scale it properly,
$$
\phi_0(x, y) = \frac{P_0(x, y)}{P_0(0, 0)} = 2 (1 - x - y) \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}\right)
$$

Now repeat for the other nodes:
$$
\phi_1(x,y) = \frac{x (1 - x - y)}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}\\
\phi_2(x,y) = \frac{x \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)}{1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}\\
\phi_3(x,y) = \frac{y \left(1 - x - y\right)}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}\\
\phi_4(x,y) = \frac{x y}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}\\
\phi_5(x,y) = \frac{y \left(y - \frac{1}{2}\right)}{1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}
$$

There is also a slightly more complicated, but more generic method for deriving nodal triangle basis based on the orthogonal modal basis and inverting the Vandermonde matrix. For more information on this method see [Hesthaven and Warburton's Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-72067-8).